# How to use a function from the view controller in the app delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have an app that is connected to a device by Bluetooth.

I want the app to send a command that indicates that the app is going to close in the app delegate method : (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {

Comment: The better approach is to have the view controller register for the associated notification. No need to have the app delegate communicate with the view controller.

Comment: Look at the notifications listed in the docs for UIApplication (or is it UIApplicationDelegate?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## One word: `NSNotificationCenter`

I'm not sure what you need to set the data to because you can't pass the data seamlessly via `NSNotificationCenter`; however you were going to figure that out in your `UIApplicationDelegate` anyway, so why can't you do it in the view controller directly.

**In your case there is no need to do *anything* in your application delegate, because this notification allows your view controller to act as a mini app delegate** (in that you can get termination status and so on).

Therefore...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(TXdata:) name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)TXdata:(NSString *) data {
    NSString *newData = data;
    if (newData == nil) {
        newData = ... // Figure out what your data should be here.
    }
    //do whatever with your data here.
}
```

I quote:

> #### [UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification)
>
> Posted when the app is about to terminate.
>
> This notification is associated with the delegate applicationWillTerminate: method. This notification does not contain a userInfo dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a class separate from the view controller and app delegate to handle the BLE communication. That way, the view controller and the app delegate can both have access and provide a better "separation of concerns" for your app. This new class might work well as a singleton.